# Changes in CGI.pm function param() behavior?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm migrating a Perl script from Perl 5.1 and it involves the following code which no longer appears to work:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use CGI ':standard';
    print header;

    if (param()) {
      if (!(param('rno'))) {     
       print ('Improper reference!');
      }
      $rno=param('rno');
    ## .. etc
    }
```

For example assuming I call the script from the www as host.com/cgi/myscript.pl?rno=20

the script should recognize the name/value pair and store the value 20 in the variable $rno and it no longer does.

Actually I think this ended up being a trick question!

In my example, I arbitrarily used a value of 20, but when I was testing, I had the query set to `rno=0` - and I suspect that triggered the behavior differently than what I anticipated.

I guess I need to tell the difference between the rno value being empty and "0"

Comment: You can try running it from the commandline with `./YourScript.cgi 'rno=20'`

Comment: I tried this with Perl 5.22.1 and CGI.pm 4.26. The snippet works when called as 'perl test_cgi.pl nro=20'. Is your Webserver set up correctly? For testing you could dump the result of calling param().

Comment: Use `defined` to test if the value is defined.

Comment: It was my bad.. the script did work, but it wouldn't work when rno=0 and as a result I thought it was broken.. in the context I was testing, with a live database, I couldn't change the parameter value and didn't realize it was a glitch with the system being unable to differentiate between 0 and null.